# How to Firebase retrieve data below UID and auto ID In Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[enter image description here][1]I'm trying to retrieve specific data from Database. I'd like to read all data in product_list

My Database

[image]

This is what i try but when i print listName. It show like this listName = nil

```
 let refList = Database.database().reference().child("Users/Sellers")
        refList.observe(DataEventType.value, with:{(snapshot) in
            if snapshot.childrenCount>0{
                self.listProduct.removeAll()

                for lists in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]{
                    let userList = lists.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                    let listName = userList?["name"]
                    let listDetail = userList?["detail"]
                    let listPrice = userList?["price"]
                    print("key = \(listName)")

                    let list = ListModel(name: listName as! String?, detail: listDetail as! String?, price: listPrice as! String?)

                    self.listProduct.append(list)
                }
                self.tableList.reloadData()
            }

        })
```

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell

        let list: ListModel
        list = listProduct[indexPath.row]

        cell.lblName.text = list.name
        cell.lblDetail.text = list.detail
        cell.lblPrice.text = list.price

        return cell
    }
```

It have 4 things i want to retrieve

(details, name, price and product_image_url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now your code is looping over the child nodes of `/Users/Sellers`, which is the nodes of each individual user. What you seem to want to do is include all nodes under the `product_list` property of each user, which requires an extra nested loop:

```
let refList = Database.database().reference().child("Users/Sellers")

refList.observe(DataEventType.value, with:{(snapshot) in
    if snapshot.childrenCount>0{
        self.listProduct.removeAll()

        for user in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]{
            let productList = user.childSnapshot(forPath: "product_list")
            for product in productList.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]{
              let userList = product.value as? [String: AnyObject]
              let listName = userList?["name"]
              let listDetail = userList?["details"] // NOTE: also fixed a typo here
              let listPrice = userList?["price"]
              print("key = \(listName)")

              let list = ListModel(name: listName as! String?, detail: listDetail as! String?, price: listPrice as! String?)

              self.listProduct.append(list)

            }
        }
        self.tableList.reloadData()
    }

})
```

Comment: Thank a lot but it have some error in line "let userList = lists.value as? [String: AnyObject]" the error show "Use of unresolved identifier 'lists'"

Comment: Now it work! I change to "let userList = product.value as? [String: AnyObject]" Thank you so much. would you mind if i have one more question about how to retrieve image from product_image_url?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39398282/retrieving-image-from-firebase-storage-using-swift, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39459555/swift-3-how-to-download-profile-image-from-firebase-storage

Comment: I try follow the link above but it still some error like this becuase i want to picture show in the cell of tableviewcell

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WT14k.png